What did Wayne Grudem mean by claiming that the canon was not "officially" decided until the Council of Trent?
In Systematic Theology chapter 3 "The Canon of Scripture", Wayne Grudem says

It was not until 1546, at the Council of Trent, that the Roman Catholic Church officially declared the Apocrypha to be part of the canon (with the exception of 1 and 2 Esdras and the Prayer of Manasseh).

(This is on page 59 in the 1st edition.) What does he mean by this? He is certainly not unaware of the Council of Carthage (397), because he cites this just 5 pages later for its decision on the NT canon. However, the Council of Carthage's Old Testament canon includes all of the Apocrypha found in modern Catholic Bibles (except Baruch). Is this an oversight on Grudem's part? Or is there some qualitative difference between the decision of the Council of Carthage and the Council of Trent that makes the latter an official declaration while the former not?
Note: Grudem also does not mention the Council of Rome (382) anywhere that I can find, which was the first council to discuss the canon and included the Apocrypha as well, but he may be following the scholarship which regards the canon list of the Decretum Gelasianum not to be genuinely derived from the Council of Rome. If so, then he would have no reason to mention it as no direct evidence of the Council of Rome's decisions exist.

The Council of Trent was an ecumenical council; the council of Rome (382) and the Council of Carthage (397) were local councils only.
The decree of Trent on Scripture after listing the books, explicitly declares anathema anyone who rejects the books "with all their parts" and "as contained in the old Latin vulgate edition":

And it has thought it meet that a list of the sacred books be inserted in this decree, lest a doubt may arise in any one's mind, which are the books that are received by this Synod.... But if any one receive not, as sacred and canonical, the said books entire with all their parts, as they have been used to be read in the Catholic Church, and as they are contained in the old Latin vulgate edition; and knowingly and deliberately contemn the traditions aforesaid; let him be anathema. Council of Trent, Session IV

Only an ecumenical council can define and declare for the entire Church. The local councils from the 4th century are valuable for understanding what the Church of that time thought about Scripture, but do not have the same weight as far as authority. Note in particular the canon is defined in terms of the contents of a previous edition, which implies the canon itself did not change at this point, but only was formally defined.

I see! It's so simple, thank you!

You're welcome.

I would clarify that the fact that there was an "old Latin vulgate edition", though, shows that the canon was not an invention of the Council of Trent.  The Catholic Church has used ecumenical councils reactively, in response to disputes and heresies.  It was only because the Protestants were promoting new canons of scripture that the Church felt it needed to reinforce the traditional canon.  I think this point is worth mentioning because Protestants and atheists will often claim that Trent invented or changed the canon of Scripture for Catholics, which is false.

@workerjoe the Councils of Hippo, of Rome and of Carthage themselves show that the canon didn't change at Trent. The question is primarily when did it "officially" get defined.

If I understand correctly, since those 4th century councils were local only, the status of the deuterocanonical books was still theoretically "in the air", as they had been questioned by some in the ancient church and there had not yet been an official, church-wide resolution to that debate. When Luther re-opened the question in the 16th century, the Catholic Church felt the need to finally close it.

@DarkMalthorp sorta, but we need to add nuance. It's not quite that they were "in the air" until Trent meaning that up until that point any book could have been declared non-canonical. Dogma is defined most often when attacked, but continued effectively undisputed use adds weight.

Yes that's why I meant by "theoretically"--the question hadn't been formally closed even if it was closed practically speaking.

My point was that on the eve of the declaration at Trent, it was far more settled than "up in the air" would imply. Even today there are theological points which while not dogma formally, are effectively beyond any real dispute.

When I was growing up, in the late 1960's, the Catholic Bibles in use had a separate section in the back where the Apocryphal books were included; kind of like an appendix.  Now, as I understand it, they are peppered throughout.  Does that indicate a change in status or acceptance?

@MikeBorden nope. There has been no change. Some bibles marketed to Catholics  are really a Protestant Bible + Apocryphal books. The first one I received was like that. Catholic Bibles (e.g Douay-rheims, Knox) have the Deuterocanonical within the Old Testament.

And always have?

@MikeBorden I have no evidence to suggest they were fundamentally different historically. The canon listed by Trent, Rome, Hippo or Carthage doesn't list the deuterocanonical texts separately; the distinction only became prominent during the Reformation.
